# Simple contour integral with a parameter gone wrong

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, complex

**Bug introduced in 7.0 and fixed in 7.0.1**

---

I run into the following problem, I tried to evaluate a very simple integral:

```
Assuming[ a > 0  , Integrate[Sin[a*s]/(s - I)^2, {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

Mathematica claims the answer is zero, even though you can evaluate it by hand using residues to convince yourself that the answer is:

$I\ a\ \pi\ e^{-a}$

What is weird, is that if you substitute some numerical value instead of `a` the answer is correct. Also if you switch the pole to be `+I` Mathematica gives an incorrect answer:

$-2\ I\ a\ \pi\cosh(a)$

instead of simply minus the previous result.
Anyone had a problem like this?

Comment: I get `E^-a Pi`. Mma v 8.0.0.0

Comment: Voting to close as TL

Comment: what version of Mathematica are you using? I get the same result as others above on 8.04 (OSX)

Comment: Emksajot, welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time you will be able to do more on the site (post graphics, edit things, etc). Another tip: after posting a question stay around for a little while, to answer questions raised by commenters. This will streamline the Q&A process considerably.

Comment: I get `E^-a Pi` from version 7.0.1

Comment: This `Assuming[a > 0, 
 Integrate[Sin[s a]/(s - I)^2, {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]]` gives your first result

Comment: Interesting... Using v7.0.0 on OS X M.L., I get zero as well... `In[1]:= Assuming[a > 0, Integrate[Sin[a*s]/(s - I), {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]]` outputs `Out[1]:= 0`. Wonder if this is the underlying issue?

Comment: @verde  I made a typo while posting the question. The pole is of order 2, like you have it, and I get the answer as described (i.e. 0 as opposed to what you get). I used v.7.0.0 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @EmKajot Even for this integral the answer is `I a E^-a Pi` not `0` as you claim. It doesn't matter if it is evaluated in `Mathematica` `v.7` or `v.8`.

Comment: The corrected function ("^2" added) gives the expected result `I a E^-a Pi` in Mma 8.

Comment: @EmKajot Perhaps you had evaluated before `a = 0;`.  But you should have got warnings like `$Assumptions::fas: Warning: One or more assumptions evaluated to False`. Try `Clear[a]`.

Comment: In[11]:= Clear[a]
Assuming[a > 0, 
 Integrate[Sin[s* a]/(s - I)^2, {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

Out[12]= 0

Comment: Well ... so it seems there was bug in v7.0.0 corrected in v7.0.1 onwards. There is not much else to do.

Comment: @Verde then maybe we mark it as a bug and tag it v.7.

Comment: @rcollyer Done!